# Is the product of two elements in a monoid also an element of that monoid?

Tags: group-theory, monoid

Let $(M, ·)$ be a monoid and $x$ and $y$ any two elements of said monoid. Is the following true?

$$∀ x, y ∈ M, \qquad  x · y ∈ M$$

Comment: That's the definition of a monoid...

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The monoid axioms are totality (the one you asked about), associativity and identity. For what it's worth, the other two axioms [define a category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Group-like_structures), so a monoid is a total category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A monoid is a triple $(M,\circ,e)$ consisting of a non-empty set $M$, an operation $\circ:M\times M\rightarrow M:(x,y)\mapsto x\circ y (=xy)$ and a neutral element $e\in M$.
So the multiplication of two elements $x,y\in M$ yields another element $xy\in M$.

Comment: Why do you need to manually specify $e$ rather than just using a $2$-tuple $(M,\,\circ)$ for which some $e\in M$ satisfies $x\circ e=e\circ x=x$ for all $x\in M$? If such an $e$ exists, it is unique because $e=e\circ f=f$ if $f$ also works.

Comment: Indeed, each semigroup can be extended to a monoid by adding a neural element.